# changing pages in an asp Master page?

Tags: html, asp.net

Pretty Newbie question here, but it's been hard to find a good example for some reason: I have a basic masterpage with some links on it when a link is pressed a javascript function is run to save some session variables. I notcied setting the href for the link will skip the onClick js function i set up. Then at the end of the function, I would like to change the Master page's contentplaceholder to a different content page. Is there a certain way this should be done?

I've only used having a postbackURL in a tag or server.transfer() in the behind code.

Comment: How would you save session variables using javascript?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure that out xD Unless there's a way to save variables on the server with out using session?

Comment: Will, I think afzalulh's question is asking how you managed to accomplish setting a session variable in javascript.  Javascript is client side.  Are mixing up some terminology here?

Comment: I used the SessionStorage object.

Answer (score 1):

`ContentPlaceHolders` don't work that way. They're set only by the page which uses the master page, not by the master page itself.

If you want to change the content, then you need to navigate to the new page.

Comment: Ah, ok. I found out about the window.location property, which seems to work for me.